# Using KSOAP with Android. Problems with custom namespace

Tags: android, namespaces, ksoap, envelope

Here's my big trouble. I'm trying to invoke a specific ws with this request:

Here's my Java code used in an Android project:

First, is it possible to print out the XML generated by this request?
Anyway, the result returned by my request is always a "fail", I think that's because the SetReport tag use a specific namespace.(e.g. <**ws:**SetReport> )
How do I specify this type of namespace in my request?? In other words, how can I create an Envelope with xmlns:xs="http://ws.comunichiamo.com" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already set the namespace when creating the `SoapObject` and that's the correct way.

You can obtain the real strings being sent between client and server by setting

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

and then looking into `androidHttpTransport.requestDump` and `responseDump` after the request.

(What is a "fail"? Is it an exception? What does it say?)

Some notes: you don't need to set the type for primitive ones like String and ints, and if you're using last version of KSoap2 there should be an `HttpTransportSE` class that is suggested to use in place of `AndroidHttpTransport`.

(+1 per user e password ;) )

Comment: Fail is the response given me by the web service.

Comment: So, it seems that I can invoke it correctly, but I must put some wrong parameters in my request...P.S. Are you italian?

Comment: @ilsologheo00 you should get some error message from the server, at least in `responseDump`. Are you getting into the catch block? If you're getting a `SoapFault` exception it should tell you if it's a server or client fault. (si' sono italiano)

Comment: @ilsologheo00 il peggior genere di messaggi d'errore. Ho visto che il webservice non e' dotnet. Hai provato con `envelope.dotNet = false`?

Comment: Yes! Adesso funziona! Ti ringrazio davvero!

Comment: For the non-Italian speaking (like me) - The solution was to set `dotNet=false`. Worked for me aswell. Seems, that this option was messing with namespaces somehow.